# Clash of clans from android to iOS but Android phone is dead

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios, android

Hi I have TH9 game on my Nexus 5 (Android phone) which is dead recently. I bought a new IPhone today and installed CoC. I cannot get code from my old phone. I neither have progress on GC. Any help appreciated.

Comment: maybe try logging into your account from another android device and then transferring it.

Comment: Well, well, well, NECRO'D

Answer (score 1):

Contact Supercell immediately through the Help and Support. Supercell will be asking for details of your account (e.g. in-game name, experience before leveling up, etc.) Supercell is kind, based on experience.

Comment: I logged into another android and set it as old device and did it like @Dragonrage said in comments.