# How to link a device in COC if the old device was lost?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm stuck with this problem.. I've been playing CoC for more than a half year and now I lost my old phone. It was an android. Now I got a new phone, which is iOS and I cannot link a device.

Is it possible somehow to recover my old account?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clash of clans from android to iOS but Android phone is dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245875/clash-of-clans-from-android-to-ios-but-android-phone-is-dead)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1. **Ask support from Supercell.** You can do this via pressing the Help and Support button in the Options menu. Pick any question and press "No" on the "Did you find this helpful?" question. Then press "Contact us" and provide them with details of your account and eventually authenticity details (***don't give them any passwords though!***). I doubt they will be able to help you, but at least it's worth trying, being the easiest method.
2. **Use a surrogate Android device.** Use an old Android device if you have any, borrow it from a trusted friend, preferably family, or buy one. Link your account to this phone via Google Play or Facebook, and then press the "Link Device" button from the Options menu from both the Android and the iOS devices. Follow the steps that appear and you're done.  ***Important: If you used another person's phone, then your Google Play or Facebook might remain permanently linked to it, so I strongly recommend that you only do this on an extremely trusted person's phone, like your parents. If you bought a phone to do this, you might just reset it to factory settings and return it to your seller.***

***If you did not have a Google Play / Facebook account linked to it, then I can't help you.***

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I bolded the important parts, underlining the essential things.

Comment: @HELPME Please tell me if it worked.

Comment: When you abuse bold and italics so much, they lose meaning and look like a mess. But if that's what you want, go ahead.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I tried to avoid the common issue of having a "wall of text". Alternating fonts usually does the trick. It looks ok for me, since I only underlined the method titles, some important security issues and the line saying that Google Play / Facebook are needed. (And I know that I'm a little stubborn, but I'm really not looking for an argument.)

Comment: I used to play a old game on BlackBerry which I registered with just a user name and password, come to find out there was a Facebook version and support easily linked it so the first part is pretty well done.